# population of elasticity tensor

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to create a code to populate a tensor with the symmetries of an elasticity tensor which should have 36 independent components and the symmetries `C[i,j,k,l] = C[j,i,k,l] = C[i,j,l,k]`.

I am doing:

```
C = sym.MutableDenseNDimArray.zeros(3,3,3,3)
var = sym.symbols('C1:%d'%82)

ct = 0
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        for k in range(3):
            for l in range(3):
                if C[i,j,k,l] == 0:
                    C[i,j,k,l] = var[ct]
                    C[j,i,k,l] = var[ct]
                    C[i,j,l,k] = var[ct]
                    ct += 1
```

This is giving me 45 different entries. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you displayed the matrix?  Any  unexpected entries?  Missing ones or overwritten. This should just be a 'bookkeeping' exercise.

Comment: this will populate the matrix with 45 entries `C45`.  I was hoping to only have 36 `C36`. As these symmetries should make the tensor only have 36 independent components

Comment: sympy support indexing (similar?) to numpy so you could simplify the nested loops

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing a symmetry. If the 2 symmetries you mentioned:

`C[i,j,k,l] = C[j,i,k,l]` (symmetry 1)
`C[i,j,k,l] = C[i,j,l,k]` (symmetry 2)

hold for every element that means that:

`C[a,b,c,d] = C[b,a,c,d]` (symmetry 1)
`C[b,a,c,d] = C[b,a,d,c]` (symmetry 2)

and therefore:

`C[a,b,c,d] = C[b,a,d,c]` or
`C[i,j,k,l] = C[j,i,l,k]` (implied symmetry)

If you include that in your code you'll get:

```
C = sym.MutableDenseNDimArray.zeros(3,3,3,3)
var = sym.symbols('C1:%d'%82)

ct = 0
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        for k in range(3):
            for l in range(3):
                if C[i,j,k,l] == 0:
                    C[i,j,k,l] = var[ct]
                    C[j,i,k,l] = var[ct]
                    C[i,j,l,k] = var[ct]
                    C[j,i,l,k] = var[ct]
                    ct += 1
```

And that should give you 36 different entries.